# Bitcoin transactions to the network

Tags: bitcoind

New to bitcoins is it possible to send transactions to the network without having a local node installed and how I'm coding in c#

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to send transactions to the network without having a
>   local node installed

Definetely yes.

> and how

- Open socket connection to someone ip:8333
- Handshake
- Send tx
- Close connection
- Quit

Comment: Thanks amaclin, do you have an example, Im running this in a console program, thanks

Comment: You maight take a look at this git: https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib

Comment: Thanks Richard but as far as I understand BitcoinLib requires that you install Bitcoin Core or at least a full node on your system